What is the role of loss functions in gradient boosting?
In gradient boosting different loss functions can be used. For example, in sklearn's GradientBoostingRegressor possible loss functions are: ‘squared_error’, ‘absolute_error’, ‘huber’, and ‘quantile’ loss functions.
I understand the effect of loss functions in gradient descent (not gradient boosting). For example, squared error loss function penalizes large errors more compared to absolute error loss function. Can we say similar things in the case of gradient boosting?

In gradient boosting, the optimization is done over the space of functions. So we use functional gradient descent as optimizer. To get a sense, see this. Gradient boosting in practice nearly always uses decision trees as the base learner.
The choice of a loss function depends on various factors, including the nature of the problem. Different loss functions emphasize different aspects of model performance and may be more suitable for specific applications. This is also true for function-level gradient descent. For example in sklearn's GradientBoostingRegressor ‘absolute_error’ refers to the absolute error of regression and is a robust loss function, as you mentioned.
To understand boosting, on CS229 notes on decision trees see 2.2 Boosting, especially 2.2.2 Gradient boosting.
